# Most efficient way to get users country in Next.js/Node.js?

Tags: node.js, performance, next.js, geoip

In a Next.js app, what would be the most efficient (fastest) way to retrieve the users country?
Among other things, I would use it to determine which scripts are loaded using next/script.

I looked in to node-geoip and fast-geoip, but even though fast-geoip has a very thorough explanation below, I do not understand the mechanisms behind Next.js/Node.js to evaluate the methods properly.

```
Concretely, what geoip-lite does is that, on startup, it reads the whole database from disk, parses it and puts it all on memory, thus this results in the startup time being increased by about ~233 ms along with an increase of memory being used by the process of around ~110 MB, in exchange for any new queries being resolved with low sub-millisecond latencies (~0.02 ms).

This works if you have a long-running process that will need to geolocate a lot of IPs and don't care about the increases in memory usage nor startup time, but if, for example, your use-case requires only geolocating a single IP, these trade-offs don't make much sense as only a small part of the satabase is needed to answer that query, not all of it.

This library tries to provide a solution for these use-cases by separating the database into chunks and building an indexing tree around them, so that IP lookups only have to read the parts of the database that are needed for the query at hand. This results in the first query taking around 9ms and subsequent ones that hit the disk cache taking 0.7 ms, while memory consumption is kept at around 0.7MB.

Wrapping it up, geoip-lite has huge overhead costs but sub-millisecond queries whereas this library doesn't have any overhead costs but its queries are slower (0.7-9 ms).
```

As geoip would be called for every visitor, I assume it would have to read the whole database on each initialization and thereby making fast-geoip the best choice?

or is there some built in mechanism, that makes sure it is accessed from memory across the subsequent requests, when frequently loaded and hence making node-geoip the best choice?

or am I focused on solving my problem the wrong way, and should rather see if there is some way I can get the location via the users browser?

Would appreciate any feedback, even if there is a completely different path worth exploring:-)

Answer (score 1):

I read the [documentation for fast-geoip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-geoip). It's designed for "serverless" cloud services such as AWS Lambda, GCP Cloud Functions, CF Workers where RAM is limited and expensive.

Note the package author's emphasis on low steady-state RAM use in the graphs below.

[image]

[image]

In summary, assuming a cloud VM/bare-metal deployment and the need to call the IP to location method on every page request, there is probably no compelling reason to use the above package.

PS: Check if the above packages require you to rotate a DB file on disk every few weeks (or rebuild+redeploy your Node app) to keep data up to date. There are commercial REST APIs such as the one in my bio (I am the developer) that may mitigate this hassle, YMMV.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.

My concern about an external API, would be the additional latency as well as severe dependency on service availability.
What measures have you taken to make your service redundant and geographically diversed accross the globe (if any)?

And what lookup method do you use, for your service? Apart from fast-geoip and geoip-lite, I also looked in to the original maxmind package, that seems more updated.

Comment: We offer HTTP/2 support at our API endpoint which means a high concurrency of requests (and responses) on the same connection (aka multiplexing) from your server. There is a caching layer in our API frontend which means <1ms response times for "popular" IPs. Constant <5ms or less backend response time. Data is automatically updated daily. We have a single AZ at this time with redundancy within it.